# Small files with Map Reduce or multi threading/multi processing

Tags: multithreading, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I've a batch of 500 files each around 45 kb. Each file requires around 87840 calculations (ARIMA regression problems) to be made. And each calculation is independent in it self.

Given this, what is the best approach to develop a solution for such a problem.

Is Elastic Map Reduce the way to go, or should I use a multi-core machine using multi-processing and multi-threading?

Answer (score 0):

If each calculation is independent, then multi-threading would be a bad Idea as you run into problems of a shared-heap and serialisation associated with that. So elastic map-reduce or in case you only have access to a multi-core machine, then use multi-processing.

Comment: Could you tell how the mappers and the reducers would look like in this case if EMR approach is adapted? The 500 files I want to process in as parallel fashion as possible. And each file also has 87840 independent calculations to done as I mention in the question.